# opcua - not getting all values in the queue after setting sample rate

Tags: python, opc-ua

This is my code in python:

```
client = Client('opc.tcp://DESKTOP-D1B43P9.mshome.net:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer')
client.connect()
counter = client.get_node("ns=3;i=1001")
handler = SubHandler()
sub = client.create_subscription(10000, handler)
handle = sub.subscribe_data_change(counter, queuesize=2)
sub.modify_monitored_item(handle, 500)
```

If I don't change the sampling rate (remove the last line), I get two values (datachange_notification is called twice in a row) every 10 seconds.
But if I do change the sampling rate, it's called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/858274721766907148b527916e97446dbbf6af6d/opcua/common/subscription.py#L312) when you call `modify_monitored_item` and don't specify the `new_queuesize` it defaults to 0, which tells the server to set it to "default" queue size, which is 1 according to the spec.